# Align div to bottom of another absolute div container

Tags: html, css

I apologize upfront if this has already been answered on SO but I'm going crazy trying to figure this out...

This code...

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Print Check Sample</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                font-family: "sans-serif";
            }
            #address {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0.25in;
                left: 0;
            }
            #check_num {
                position:absolute;
                top: 0;
                right: 0.5in;
                font-size: 0.2in;
            }
            #container {
                position: relative;
                margin: 0.25in;
                width: 100%;
                height:3.5in;
                border: 1px gray solid;
            }
            #date {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0.5in;
                right: 1.5in;
                font-size: 0.15in;
            }
            #pay_line {
                float: left;
                width: 10.5in;
                border:2px red dashed;
            }
            #pay_line_container {
                position: absolute;
                top: 1.8in;
                border:2px green dashed;
            }
            #pay_line_message {
                float:left;
                width:1in;
                font-size: 0.15in;
                border:2px blue dashed;
            }
            #void_message {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0.75in;
                right: 0.1in;
                font-size: 0.2in;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="check_num">1000</div>
            <div id="address">
                <b>Estate Of JAMES SMITH</b><br>
                35 Addison Avenue<br>
                New York, NY 00000<br>
                (123)456-7890
            </div>
            <div id="date">
                <i>Date</i>&nbsp;<u>02/08/2012</u>
            </div>
            <div id="void_message">
                <b>VOID 180 DAYS FROM CHECK DATE</b>
            </div>
            <div id="pay_line_container">
                <div id="pay_line_message">
                    <i>Pay To The Order Of:</i>
                </div>
                <div id="pay_line"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is producing this image...

[image: pay check sample]

I've tried using various combos of "float" and "relative" and "height" but I can't figure out how to make the `<div id="pay_line"></div>` (red border) align to the bottom of the `<div id="pay_line_container">` (green border) container.

This needs to work specifically in IE8.

Can one of you please help this frustrated coder figure out how to do this?

Comment: As per answers, position absolute and bottom could be the way forward.  But I think that there's something on your page (not in the simplified version) that's corrupting it - having saved it locally the red div IS aligning to the bottom in IE8 for me but the divs are overrunning to the right.

Comment: @KAJ - I saw that happen when I tried it on JS Fiddle and also in Chrome - not sure why on that.  Using absolute and bottom did do the trick after all...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try making it:

```
#pay_line {
  position: absolute; 
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 74px;
}
```

Comment: Man, I thought I tried that earlier and it was failing, but that does the trick...go figure.  I had read several posts saying use absolute and bottom of 0 and I thought I tried it but guess I didn't plug it in right...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but to get it to the bottom, couldn't you just position it absolutely and use bottom: 0? This should work in IE8.

```
#pay_line {position: absolute; bottom: 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `vertical-align: baseline` to your `#pay_line` ID.